# Can I use a B1 visa if I didn't attend the conference for which it was requested?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I have a valid B1 visa which was supposed to be used to go to a conference, but I didn't attend. Is there a chance I would be challenged at the US port of entry if I were to use it for something else? Would I be asked to present documentation? What if the conference is passed and I had other business to take care of in my home country? is there any chance of being refused entry?

Comment: Did you miss the conference after entering the US, or did you skip the trip to the US altogether?  If you are not in the US now, when do you plan to return, and for what purpose?

Comment: Did you already enter the US? Or are you planning a new journey?

Comment: Typically not, as U.S. visas are almost always multiple-entry and most of the time the officer can't care less about why you initially applied for the visa. They will almost always only be interested in what you are doing this time. But it will depend on your personal circumstances, which we know nothing about.

Comment: I have a B1/B2 visa that I got to attend some meetings. It is a multiple-entry.I already used for other proposals, like training and vacations. I never had issues.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.